# Incompatibility error when using make to run a c file on lubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make

So I'm starting to get familiar with makefiles.

> I have 3 files: add.s, main.c, numbers.c where there is a call to an
>   assembly function from main

so I figured I'm gonna need to state that as a dependency. 
I wrote this makefile:

```
output: main.o add.o numbers.o
    gcc main.o add.o numbers.o -o output

main.o: main.c add.s
    gcc -m32 -c main.c

numbers.o: numbers.c
    gcc -m32 -c numbers.c

add.o: add.s
    nasm -f elf32 add.s -o add.o

clean:
    rm -rf *.o output
```

and ran it on lubuntu and I got this error:

[image]

any idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple: you have to add the `-m32` to the link line as well, not just the compile lines.

Really you should just use make's built-in facilities for compiling code and set appropriate variables, and it will handle it for you.  This will work:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -m32

output: main.o add.o numbers.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

add.o: add.s
        nasm -f elf32 $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -rf *.o output
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/ for docs.